# Converting yml file to using windows command for creating directory

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I'm trying to follow a tutorial that creates a kafka container by running "docker compose up" with the yml file below.  Since I'm running windows, the author had mentioned to replace cd with PWD.  So I tried "%cd%/.data:/bitnami.  But the error I get is:

```
Named volume "%cd%\.data:/bitnami:rw" is used in service "zookeeper" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.
```

Here is the yml file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/zookeeper:3.7
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      - "${PWD}/.data:/bitnami"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
    networks:
      - lab01
  kafka:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    volumes:
      - "${PWD}/.data:/bitnami"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=host.docker.internal:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - lab01

networks:
  lab01:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: PWD should work fine on Windows since it's running in a Linux hypervisor. Now, if your current directory is not mounted into the hypervisor, is a different problem... Also, 1) Kafka doesn't require Zookeeper anymore, and the bitnami image does not use it, or Zookeeper connect variable 2) don't use host.docker.internal for Zookeeper since it's running in Compose, not your host machine

Answer (score 0):

the volume you mounted is assumed to be named volume but in you case you are mounting the host directory.

check once if using full path solves the issue.

```
volumes:
    - "C:/Users/jane/Desktop/.data:/bitnami"
```